# Silverstripe CMS: Setting custom logotype, site name and logout action in admin CMS

Tags: silverstripe-4

I would like to change the logotype that appears on the very top of left menu when collapsed (in admin area). Additionally I would like to edit the logout action beside “myprofile”.
Both above the left menu that can be manipulated through SilverStripe\Admin\ModelAdmin extension.

with this example I can add a new menu item. But how can I edit the header of this menu??

```
<?php
use SilverStripe\Admin\ModelAdmin;

class CustomAdmin extends ModelAdmin
{

    private static $url_segment = 'myprofile';

    private static $menu_title = 'My Product Admin';

    private static $menu_icon = 'themes/mddsz/images/icon_home.svg';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer/solution from the [Silverstripe forum](https://forum.silverstripe.org/t/setting-custom-logotype-site-name-and-logout-action-in-admin-cms/6793).

Basically I copied the admin templates to my app and edited from there.